# Retrieve Text file content from Bitbucket

Tags: json, rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I want to Read the text file which is uploaded in BitBucket through REST Api.

URL: https://{username}:{token}/bitbucket.org/rest/api/1.0/{path}.

This gives JSON of folder content. I wanted to read text file and to extract the content. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In term of API, make sure to not use the [V1, which is deprecated for BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html).

One API endpoint which returns the content of a file would then be [`/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/src`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/src)

> If the path matches a file, then the raw contents of the file are returned (unless the format=meta query parameter was provided, in which case a json document containing the file's meta data is returned).
>
> If the path matches a directory, then a paginated list of file and directory entries is returned (if the format=meta query parameter was provided, then the json document containing the directory's meta data is returned).